# Longest Collatz sequence Efficiency

Tags: python

I am trying to answer [Problem 14 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), unfortunately my code takes longer than necessary to run. How can I make it efficient, I have reduced it but it still lacks the efficiency. My code is below

```
my_seq_final = []
for i in range(1000000, 0, -1):
    ans = i
    my_seq = [ans]
    while ans != 1:
        n = ans
        if n % 2 == 0:
            ans = n/2
        else:
            ans = 3*n + 1
        my_seq.append(ans)
    my_seq_final.append(my_seq)

tmp = 0
result = [0]
for j in my_seq_final[::-1]:
    if tmp < len(j):
        tmp = len(j)
        result[0] = j
    else:
        pass
print(result[0][0])
```

Comment: What is "project 14" of Project Euler ask - what does this code do? Also, if this code works, you might be better of posting to Code Review than SO. "How do I make this faster" isn't really a bug. I don't see any obvious efficieny holes here (append is amortized O(1), though not constant worst case). Facesious ways to make it faster: write it in C, get a better computer, travel faster so that there's time dialation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid calculating many times the same Collatz sequence.

```
cache = {1: 1}
def collatz_count(n):
    if n not in cache:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            cache[n] = 1 + collatz_count(n // 2)
        else:
            cache[n] = 1 + collatz_count(3 * n + 1)
    return cache[n]
```

Suppose I call this function with 6:

```
 In []: collatz_count(6)
 Out[]: 9
```

This is the length of the sequence `[6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]`. Moreover, the cache has been modified by side-effect:

```
 {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 8, 4: 3, 5: 6, 6: 9, 8: 4, 10: 7, 16: 5}
```

Thereafter, if I call the function with 12, the length (10) of the sequence `[12, 6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]` will be calculated very quickly, since the second term (6) is already associated to its length.

In your problem, most of the required lengths will be simply retrieved from the cache or calculated through very few recursive calls.

Specifically, in the specified range, the average number of calls to `collatz_count` is:

- 310.534203 (without cache);
- 3.16861 (with cache).

PS: Note that I have chosen to implement my cache as a Python dictionary. The generated Collatz numbers grow indeed far above the given bound of `10**6` (namely, 56,991,483,520 is the maximal "intermediate" value). An array of this size would be 99.9961% empty, and nevertheless require at least ~111 GB (2 bytes per value).

Comment: All great but you need to specify value of 2 in dictionary otherwise you get wrong step count along the line. 2 require 1 step not 2. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also thanks for sharing. This is beautifully simple and probably most efficient way to calculate it. It made me learn about recursion and I spent great deal of time try to understand it until I got it. For anyone wondering I recommend below video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv9NEXX1VHc

Comment: You could replace `cache[n] = 1 + collatz_count(n / 2)` with `cache[n] = 1 + collatz_count(n // 2)` since we expect integers in the image of the operation anyway. [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/b1eee59bf2ebd3cb0c727d8002c252b7) is a gist.

Comment: Corrected, thanks. It was Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the code correctly, you are saving all the sequences, and at the end deciding which is the longest.

You can surely reduce the memory consumption, and therefore speed things up, simply by determining the length of the current sequence and then comparing it with the longest sequence found so far. If you need to print it, then you can save it.

You can speed things up by recording the length of the sequence from `n` in an array.  Then when you try a new number, you can check whether the length from that number is already known, and if so, simply add the length to the current sequence length.  This uses memory, but less memory than recording whole sequences.

Comment: Your first suggestion sounds good. For the second one, I think it would be better to use a hash table than an array as a lookup-table. The biggest Collatz number generated is no less than 56991483520.